# Совместимость dll на Win 8 ARM и x86

Tags: c++, winapi, arm, x86-64

Как я понимаю, написанные `dll` на `Win32` работать в `Win 8 ARM` отказываются.

Как можно написать нативную `dll`, которая будет работать и на x86 и на `ARM`.
Может `WinRT` позволяет написать такую `dll`?

Comment: > **нативную** dll, которая будет работать и на x86 и на ARM

Вы сами себе ответили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пиши кроссплатформенный код и компилируй его для обеих платформ. В чём проблема? Наверняка программу, использующую только WinRT можно будет скомпилировать под x86 и ARM без изменений.

А вот `dll\exe`, написанные под .NET будут работать даже без перекомпиляции. Уже тестировал на своём телефоне, хотя там даже не Windows, а Linux, .NET exe'шники работают через Mono. А уж на Windows Phone и Windows 8 ARM точно запустятся.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вряд ли. И это логично. Разные процессоры. Нужно делать две разные длл для разных осей.
Но вот длл, написаная под .NET, скорее всего, должна работать.